# How can I make it response immediately in Cocoa?

Tags: xcode, cocoa

I am making a Color Detector
It works like
If X,Y coordinate's color is not equal to textfield color then return to F


My programme:

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.000001, repeats: true, block:
{ timer in
    if(self.textcolor.stringValue != self.nowColor.stringValue){
        self.effect.stringValue = "F";
    }
})
```

But it still delay 0.5s~1seconds to return F

Does anything else in Cocoa can make it change immediately and the apps run in background?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RJZd.gif)

Comment: Polling 1 million times per second is horrible. *Don't ask, tell*. Better get notified when the mouse is moving.

Comment: nope i want it auto run in background 0.01sec is ok , 
0.5s delay is too much..

Comment: What is the delay with time interval 0.01?

Comment: also the same 0.5s~1s delay,idk why..

Comment: PS: There is a reason for 60fps. 1/60 = 0,016 interval. Do you need more than 60fps? And checking stringValue with timer is PURE HORRIBLE and RUBBISH!!! Cocoa has NSTextFieldDelegate / textDidChange notification or you can subclass and send custom notification.

Comment: This is not the right approach. Look at NSTrackingArea. The system will call you much more efficiently than this. Delays of >0.5s, however, generally mean you're trying to change UI elements on a background thread. That's not allowed.

Comment: i knew mouse move event can make it response immediately,
so is it possible if there is a way to make the virtual mouse move like x y+-0??? idk...

Comment: and i can implement the apps run in background without my real input???

Comment: How or when do `self.textcolor` and `self.nowColor` change? Which color do you want to detect?